# Grant access on BigQuery based on table prefix

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam, google-dataplex

I need to grant a group of users conditional access as `bigquery.dataEditor` on tables that start with a certain prefix.

**Example :**
The group should only have access to tables starting with the word "alpha_"

Is it possible to propagate this condition via `IAM` or via `Dataplex` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on this https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#resources it appears conditional role bindings is not support for BigQuery, therefore, the easiest solution will to create a separate datasets with all the tables with selected prefix and then grant the specific users data editor role for those tables under new dataset